# Composer Local Project Reference

Tags: php, visual-studio, composer-php

I would like to seperate my application into different Composer projects (Domain, UI, Infrastructure, etc.), each with their own dependencies, and reference them from the main project.

Much like how it works in Visual Studio: create multiple (local) projects and add references between them:

[image: Example how its done in Visual Studio]

Is it possible to do something like that using Composer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Composer now supports local repositories. See https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but it is more work than you probably think...
Because composer relies on its built-in versioning, you have to host a [private repository](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#hosting-your-own), which you then have to link to in your composer files.

Comment: Thanks. That's not ideal... Do you maybe know a way to accomplish it without Composer?

Comment: Well, you could always include a different projects `vendor/autoload.php` (or other autoloaders).  Don't know how to setup vcs so that you get code completion, though.